# Can the ip of the submitter be recorded in form data in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Need to record the ip on signature forms for added legality.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an undocumented feature of [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

In order to include the Ip Address on the Confirmation Page, in a notification email, etc. you can add the following in the content editor: `[Entry.Origin.IpAddress]`

You can also add a `Calculation` field of type `Text` with the following calculation: `=Entry.Origin.IpAddress`.  This field can then be marked as `Show This Field - Internally` to allow you to see it when managing entries but not show it to the submitter.