# Allow form to only be submitted once per user

Tags: cognito-forms

We are using Cognito Forms for a survey and would like to prevent a single person from submitting the questionnaire more than once.

Does Cognito Forms offer a function or option like this, and if so where/how do I set this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature to do this automatically.  You can capture the ip address of the submitter in the entry ([see here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88472/can-the-ip-of-the-submitter-be-recorded-in-form-data-in-cognito-forms)).  That at least would let you discard additional submissions from the same source after the fact.

Answer (score -2):

Add a username column to the form.. and using some js you can check if that username is already present then that particular user is not allowed to fill the form